# How to get video streams from FusionPBX video conference room

Tags: sip, freeswitch, fusionpbx, sipjs

I'm using SIP.js to connect to FusionPBX video conference room, but when callers join, all callers get a single caller video stream.

How can I get all streams in the room to handle them and view them to each others so everyone can see everyone video?

Is there any event I can use? like `on("join")` or something? So when someone connect I get his stream?

SIP.js have that events, but it works only on peer to peer, not in rooms.

Is there another way to make it work with FreeSWITCH?

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `FusionPBX` settings, but in his core (`FreeSWITCH`) in [mod_conference](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_conference) is parameter like `video-mode`.

> The mode to run video conferencing in. `passthrough` is non transcoded video follow audio. `transcode` allows for better switching and multiple codecs. `mux` allows for multiple parties on the video canvas at the same time